# Microphone not working on Intel NUC5CPYH

Tags: sound, microphone

Using above barebones computer with 8GB memory running Trusty, I am able to play audio on usb speakers when connected by VGA (or monitor's speakers when connected by hdmi). However, I am not able to use either a microphone connected to the computer's headphone/microphone jack's socket (is it normal to have the same socket for headphone & microphone) or a webcam (with inbuilt microphone) connected to that socket.. There is no other socket for a microphone. Both these input devices work on another computer, also with Trusty installed. I have tested this with Pulse Audio Volume Control: the port showing as Analogue Output or Microphone Unplugged (perhaps I should have rebooted?). Also alsamixer shows 0<>0 for Mic but 100<>100 for MicBoos.

Comment: More information:
I forgot to mention that I'm using Linux kernel 4.3.3 (i.e. I upgraded the kernel from version 3 as used in Trusty) as that is required to make the wireless chip on an NUC 5CPYH work. I've tried the https://help.ubuntu.com/communitySou...otingProcedure.  Step 3 says to install oem-audio-hda-daily-dkms (or any of the equivalent packages for other Ubuntu versions), but I'm not able to install it as Synaptic shows that there are no packages of the form oem-audio* in the Ubuntu repos.
I've used alsamixer to set mic to 100 but doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found Launchpad answer "No audio input with Ubuntu 14.04 and Intel NUC" (#270122). This defined the same problem as I have. It states "Turns out the jack is not a straightforward microphone jack, but one intended for a headphone and mic set. A splitter can be bought which splits it into two". As I previously said I knew that the socket is a combined one for headphone & microphone, but I didn't realise that a splitter is required for the actual microphone to be 'picked up'. I've ordered a splitter: when it comes, I'll post the result (from using it) here.e
PS I was using Linux kernel 4.3.3 in order to make wifi work (as opposed to kernel 3.19.0 as used by Trusty). I've reverted to kernel 4.2.0-22 as it's on the Trusty repos (and makes wifi work) rather than revert to 4.3.3 (which is intended for Xenial which I downloaded from the Linux kernels website).

Comment: I spoke too soon about the Trusty repos & Linux kernel 4.2.0. When I rebooted after installing it, the screen displayed lots of blocks & white. So I rebooted, interrupted Grub by using the Shift key, selected Advanced Ubuntu & selected 3.19.0 which resulted in a successful boot & login. I then removed 4.2.0 (using Synaptic), installed kernel 4.3.3 (downloaded from the Linux kernels website & rebooted : everything OK now (except for microphone as previously stated).

Comment: Headphone & microphone splitter cable solves problem.